How to compare frequencies of type of stress events with repeated measurements over time in a weekly diary study?
We hope you can help clarify whether a Chi-square test of equal frequencies (in SPSS) would be the correct choice.
Study participants have reported experienced stress events (text variable) in a weekly diary and we subsequently categorized the stress events into different types of stress (0=absent, 1=present).
We created at least 5 (or more) categories of stress events. We want to know whether the frequencies (proportions) of these categories differ significantly from each other in a sample of 700 children, and thus which types of stress events occur most frequently.
The weekly diary was reviewed by a clinician every 8 weeks during a clinic visit. Thus, each visit can contain several stress events over the past 8 weeks (mostly 1-4 events). The study participants were followed for about 1 year with several study visits.
We wondered whether the Chi-square test would be correct, since perhaps the repeated reporting of certain stress events over time may not be independent from each other?
Would it be correct to just sum up all events (as per type) over the study period?

Chi square is not designed for <5 counts per category.  If you want to Chi-sq, then you will need to sum up multiple visits.  Are you at all interested in the results from the start to end of the year? or it is just a matter of the number of stress events across each partcipant?
